# Error in deploying my code to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

My simple application which just fetches the contents from a given URL is working fine on local server, but on deployment gives error. [Check here](http://compare-hatke.appspot.com/)

The application consists of just two files which I am including here

compare-hatke.py

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url = "http://www.google.com/"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
  print(result.content)
```

app.yaml

```
application: compare-hatke
version: 3
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: compare-hatke.app
```

Log - Version 1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 269, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'compare-hatke' from '/base/data/home/apps/s~compare-hatke/1.365150810067162164/compare-hatke.pyc'> has no attribute app
```

Now, I am completely clueless why this is not working. Any suggestion or help would be crucial.

Thanks !

Comment: What are the logs in the console?

Comment: There's no `app` defined in `compare-hatke` module. Replace `compare-hatke.app` with  `compare-hatke` in .yaml file. My guess is, it'll throw a different error after that. Although, I am not sure what you're trying to do. This doesn't look like WSGI compliant. Definitely refer the docs.

Comment: I am trying to print the content of the url specified , thats it . on Removing .app , it throws Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 223, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @Rahul How to make it WSGI compliant ?

Comment: Check the `MainPage` example [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Script_Handlers). Again, refer the docs.